# HP Pavilion DV7: Keypad not working on Linux

Tags: linux, laptop, drivers, keyboard

I've recently got a HP DV7 laptop for free from a friend:

[image: HP DV7]

As you can see in the picture, the laptop features a (modified) full size keyboard, including numeric key pad.

The keyboard works as expected under Windows, but on Linux, I can't get the keypad to function. None of the keypad keys seem to produce any keycode, Even Numlock won't turn on. However, I don't believe the keyboard is physically damages, as it worked OK on Windows, and the four buttons right above the keypad, at the top edge, work fine.

When testing the keys on the console with `showkey` and on X with `xev`, the keys do absolutely nothing, all other keys send keycodes as expected.

The keyboard has an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, to access some media keys located under the F-keys.
I discovered, some other, weird behaviour with the Fn-key: When I hold down Fn, and press 'jkl' I get '123'! So, it's as if there was a laptop keypad embedded onto the main block (as it is quite often, when the keypad itself is missing).

Now, I believe because of the "duality" of the nature of this keyboard, it confuses the driver. Any ideas how I might solve this? As the keys do absolutely nothing, I have no idea where to even start.

---

I tried setting the Numlock status programatically under X with `numlockx on`: didn't work.
I also tried setting the flag and LED on the linux console with `setleds +num`: `setleds -v` now reports the flag and LED is set, but the Numpad is still not working, and the LED isn't on either.

Comment: if you install and run `numlockx` do you see any change in behaviour? you may also want to make sure you have the keyboard set as US 105 key, and disable Mouse Keys under accessibility options. I've had this issue with my DV9 over the years, but usually got it worked out.

Comment: @FrankThomas `numlockx on` has no effect. "Generic 105-key" is selected. Mouse keys are disabled.

Comment: I did this: Entered BIOS, went to the BIOS password setting, and tried to use the keys there: Numlock won't turn on, and the keys do absolutely nothing. Is the keyboard just broken after all?

Comment: I tried on the linux console using `setleds +num`. `setleds -v` reports num is set and flag is set, but the numpad still doesn't work at all. Even on the text mode console.

Comment: what distro are you using, with what desktop?

Comment: @FrankThomas I use Fedora 20 with XFCE. The keys don't work in text mode either, though. I tried with Linux Minx, NetBSD, and booted into the installation routine of Windows XP, the keys didn't work there either. I can't believe it's the keyboard itself, though. The keyboard has no controller, the button matrix is directly attached to the mainboard.

Comment: have you tried anything other than XFCE? Mate/Gnome3/cinnamon, etc?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to solve the problem, and it wasn't obvious at all.

The "InsydeH2O" BIOS had to be flashed from version F.0A to version F.2D. I don't know what caused it, but it seems the BIOS got corrupt at some point.

What have I done to fix the Numlock issue? Upagrading the EFI BIOS, which was nothing easy to do.

As a Linux user, I made a FreeDOS boot image, and booted from USB drive. The BIOS comes with a weird update tool from Compal, the Chinese company that built the chassis an the motherboard of this laptop. fishing out the correct ROM image required several hours and a Virtual Machine, as well as a lot of hair-pulling.

Eventually found a program (from Insyde, actually) that'll run on DOS, so FreeDOS it is...
The Flashing tool comes from a rather dubious location on Mediafire, I have no idea where this program originally comes from, there was no URL to be found in the program, etc.

After puzzling a bootable, minimal FreeDOS, with the flash tool and the ROM image, I've installed the SYSLINUX bootloader onto the USB stick, and booted from it.

It took two attempts at flashing the BIOS correctly, but after that, the keyboard works just fine.

The DVD/BD-Combo drive is a little bit broken on this laptop, so I couldn't boot from there. the flash utilities that come inside the archive from HP, won't work on Windows PE, which I've tried to use for several hours.